# Why can't I ping a Windows 7 box until I ping the other way first?

Tags: windows, ping

I discovered an odd thing with my Windows 7 box the other day: I can't ping it from any of my Linux boxes unless I ping them from the Windows box first. And by "I can't ping" I mean that there is no ICMP response received by the Linux boxes.

Windows tells me that the Windows Firewall is off, but I have spent the last few years avoiding supporting Windows so a lot of the networking UI in Windows is now strange and alien to me. The box is pretty new; it replaced a Windows 2000 box which died. I do most of my computing on Linux and really only need the Widnows for a small number of Windows-specific tasks, including my workplace's VPN.

Comment: As far as you know?  It is worth checking this as this is exactly the behaviour I would expect if the W7 firewall was on.

Comment: Describing the problem just as "I can't ping" isn't very helpful. What *precisely* goes wrong when you try to ping? Does the ARP cache get populated? Do the pings go out over the wire? And so on. Are you pinging by IP address or by hostname? If by hostname, do you get the IP address resolved?

Comment: Updated the question. Pinging by IPv4 address (in both directions). If I start a ping from the Linux box, no ICMP replies are received until I send an ICMP ping from the Windows box. Then ping works normally until a couple of minutes after I stop sending the Windows box any traffic from that Linux box.